# Android: Cover the current activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

I want to cover the screen of my current activity with a full screen page.

Now I'm call another activity that is set not to have ActionBar, but I'm sure there's a better way to do that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: your current method seems reasonable enough.

Comment: I have to use this thing about every five seconds! Activity are very expensive, aren't they?

Comment: I think that is acceptable in the circumstances. The alternatives would be no better IMO.

Comment: I think you could also create a DialogFragment and act on it dynamically in the activity you want to cover. That would mean only 1 fragment to create and no back and forth in the activities. What do you think?